# NVidia driver takes 8-12 GB of nonpaged memory when running Anno 1800

Tags: windows-10, memory

Well during Black Friday I bought the Season Passes and wanted to get back into Anno 1800. Loaded my old save game (mid-game so already lots of buildings and stuff going on in the world) and it immediately started to lag and hang for 2-10 seconds. Absolutely unplayable.

I checked my task manager and it said Anno was taking up about 8GB of RAM. In total processes took about 10 maybe. I got 16 GB of RAM and usage was at 98-99% all the time. So I looked into it and found out that a lot is going "behind the scenes" - something I've noticed only playing Anno so far. I remember that I never had the problem when it came out but now I can only play it on a new save. And even with a clean world it starts out with 90% RAM being used.

I just tried it again and here we go: 5 GB is used when looking at the Task Manager. **12 GB** are used by *NVRM* when looking at Poolmon. NVRM is (as far as I know) the NVidia driver. I never experienced this behavior with any other game. So it this some major issue with the graphics driver / the game or what? I bought another 16 GB as a quick fix, but this seems odd to me. I can't believe Anno is sucking up this much memory and even if, I don't see why most of it would be non-paged memory that does not even show up in the task manager.

My computer's specs are the following: i5-6600k@4x4.5 GHz, 16 GB DDR4-3000, 11 GB Geforce GTX 1080 Ti running on latest Windows 10 2020H2 with latest NVidia drivers

[image: Task Manager]

[image: Poolmon]

Comment: As a generic approach, I can typically prevent 100% RAM by limiting the specific application/process's max. allowed ram usage; for instance SQL has an easy way to set the max. usage and setting it can prevent system crashes. Even though it could use more RAM than the hardware has, by preventing 100% usage it prevents Windows and SQL fighting over it and ends up performing better - is there a way to set Anno's ram allowance? Also, what is your [virtual memory](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-change-virtual-memory-size-windows-10) set to on your computer? This can also sometimes solve issues.

Comment: Not that I know of any. Well virtual memory is set to 12 GB, so should be plenty. As said, I don't think the graphics driver should use that much memory...

Comment: I found a forum discussing that Anno might have a memory leak issue, and that even if you had 64GB RAM, you'd still eventually run out of RAM due to the leak, it would just take longer to get there. Some users report success using a memory optimizer software that can trim unutilized RAM, such as Process Lasso.

Comment: If your virtual memory is set to 12GB that could potentially be a problem, set the virtual memory to automatic and see if there is any difference with performance. I have noticed both virtual memory being set too high and too low causing issues, and sometimes letting the system handle it dynamically fixes it.

Comment: I overlooked it - it's automatic but currently 12 GB. Well it does not look like a memory leak. If it leaked memory then it would start with low usage, going up until it crashes. It does not crash, it just starts lagging at some point and the memory usage is constantly at almost maximum. Lagging starts only after a few hours or on mid- to late-game maps with lots of buildings and stuff.